# How would I design a website like this, where half the vertical page is one texture, and the other different?

Tags: html, css

http://panic.com/transmit/

I'm used to just adding a background to the body that then takes over the whole page, but with this website they're interesting in that they split it up. If I just use divs, they have whitepsace on the sides, unlike with body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I just use divs, they have whitepsace on the sides, unlike with body.

Set the margin and padding on the body element to 0.

Comment: Question, though, upon applying this I still run into issues with the vertical height. Should I use positioning to fix this, or is there a more elegant way to do it? http://i.imgur.com/cDCw1.png

Comment: Adjust margins as desired. Pay attention to the rules for collapsing margins (since you are likely seeing margins on the heading that stick out of the div).